# Libcurl wont send cookies on a redirect

Tags: c, http, redirect, cookies, libcurl

I've written some C++ code (using libcurl) to log into a WordPress blog. However I'm having an interesting problem. Libcurl isnt sending the appropriate cookies after a successful login.
First I GET the login page (to parse post data and get a cookie that WP requires). That does what it's supposed to, you see libcurl has appropriately "Added cookie wordpress_test_cookie." Next I POST the login data. WordPress login implements a redirect after successful a login. As you can see from the 302 response and Location field in the header. I was also given the cookies so that I can now navigate to the wp-admin panel. Next I grab the redirect location and try to GET it. That's where it fails.

Compiled using:

```
g++-5 -o loginTest loginTest.cpp -lcurl -std=c++17
```

g++ version:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 5.1.0-0ubuntu11~14.04.1) 5.1.0
```

curl version:

```
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
```

Complete code:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string ParseLoginPageForPOSTParameters(string loginPageBody);
size_t MyWriteCallback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);

int main() {
    CURL *curl;

    if (curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_NOTHING) != 0) {
        cerr << "Something catastrophic happened during global init" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {
        //First get the login page (to parse post data and get a cookie that WP requires)
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/wp-login.php");
        //Empty string for encoding means accept all that are supported
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 0);
        string loginPageBody = "";
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &loginPageBody);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &MyWriteCallback);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);

        //We now have the login page stored in loginPageBody
        string parsedPostParameters = ParseLoginPageForPOSTParameters(loginPageBody);
        string completePostParameters = "log=<myUsername>&pwd=<myPassword>" + parsedPostParameters;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, completePostParameters.c_str());
        curl_easy_perform(curl);

        //We now sent the login info
        char *newUrl;
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL, &newUrl);
        cout << flush;
        cout << "Redirecting to " << newUrl << endl;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, newUrl);
        string afterLoginBody = "";
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &afterLoginBody);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &MyWriteCallback);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        cout << flush;
        cout << afterLoginBody;
    } else {
        cerr << "Couldnt easy_init" << endl;
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return 0;
}

string ParseLoginPageForPOSTParameters(string loginPageBody) {
    string postParameters = "";
    //find all input tags, they're formatted like this
    //  <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />

    regex inputRegex(R"V.S.(<input.*?/>)V.S.", regex::icase|regex::optimize);
    auto firstInputMatch = sregex_iterator(loginPageBody.begin(), loginPageBody.end(), inputRegex);
    auto lastInputMatch = sregex_iterator();

    for (sregex_iterator i = firstInputMatch; i != lastInputMatch; ++i) {
        //for each input field in the form
        smatch inputMatch = *i;
        string inputMatchString = inputMatch.str();
        regex nameRegex(R"V.S.(name="(.*?)")V.S.", regex::icase|regex::optimize);
        regex valueRegex(R"V.S.(value="(.*?)")V.S.", regex::icase|regex::optimize);
        smatch nameMatch, valueMatch;
        if (regex_search(inputMatchString,nameMatch,nameRegex) && regex_search(inputMatchString,valueMatch,valueRegex)) {
            //Found a name and value pair inside the input field
            string value = valueMatch[1].str();
            string name = nameMatch[1].str();
            if (name != "log" && name != "pwd" && name != "" && value != "") {
                postParameters += "&"+name+"="+value;
            }
        }
    }
    return postParameters;
}

size_t MyWriteCallback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
    //userdata is a std::string
    size_t dataAmnt = size * nmemb;
    string *userdataString = (string*)userdata;
    for (int i=0; i<nmemb; ++i) {
        *userdataString += ptr[i];
    }
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

Complete output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying <IP of example.com>...
* Connected to example.com (<IP of example.com>) port 80 (#0)
> GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 17 Oct 2015 15:56:43 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 4759
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=30
* Server Apache/2 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
< Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Pragma: no-cache
* Added cookie wordpress_test_cookie="WP+Cookie+check" for domain example.com, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
* Found bundle for host example.com: 0x9a0c10
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host example.com
* Connected to example.com (<IP of example.com>) port 80 (#0)
> POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check
Content-Length: 115
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 115 out of 115 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Sat, 17 Oct 2015 15:56:44 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 215
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=30
* Server Apache/2 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
< Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Pragma: no-cache
* Replaced cookie wordpress_test_cookie="WP+Cookie+check" for domain example.com, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
* Added cookie wordpress_0c9410477a030adc6c64b9a4a70917f3="admin%7C1446307004%7CF38piRdUOaqnMHaJnETwYyMAdIU5Wsjq4quj9bDloZr%7C2bd7e640536c134e3426ef89f1a62b44bd011a4d93d5ffa88f336167d1144fb2" for domain example.com, path /wp-content/plugins, expire 1446350204
< Set-Cookie: wordpress_0c9410477a030adc6c64b9a4a70917f3=admin%7C1446307004%7CF38piRdUOaqnMHaJnETwYyMAdIU5Wsjq4quj9bDloZr%7C2bd7e640536c134e3426ef89f1a62b44bd011a4d93d5ffa88f336167d1144fb2; expires=Sun, 01-Nov-2015 03:56:44 GMT; path=/wp-content/plugins; httponly
* Added cookie wordpress_0c9410477a030adc6c64b9a4a70917f3="admin%7C1446307004%7CF38piRdUOaqnMHaJnETwYyMAdIU5Wsjq4quj9bDloZr%7C2bd7e640536c134e3426ef89f1a62b44bd011a4d93d5ffa88f336167d1144fb2" for domain example.com, path /wp-admin, expire 1446350204
< Set-Cookie: wordpress_0c9410477a030adc6c64b9a4a70917f3=admin%7C1446307004%7CF38piRdUOaqnMHaJnETwYyMAdIU5Wsjq4quj9bDloZr%7C2bd7e640536c134e3426ef89f1a62b44bd011a4d93d5ffa88f336167d1144fb2; expires=Sun, 01-Nov-2015 03:56:44 GMT; path=/wp-admin; httponly
* Added cookie wordpress_logged_in_0c9410477a030adc6c64b9a4a70917f3="admin%7C1446307004%7CF38piRdUOaqnMHaJnETwYyMAdIU5Wsjq4quj9bDloZr%7Ca5b38cc8bb0d656573d147fcfc00e54016271723bee9bf3613c5c45f504b2aca" for domain example.com, path /, expire 1446351204
< Set-Cookie: wordpress_logged_in_0c9410477a030adc6c64b9a4a70917f3=admin%7C1446307004%7CF38piRdUOaqnMHaJnETwYyMAdIU5Wsjq4quj9bDloZr%7Ca5b38cc8bb0d656573d147fcfc00e54016271723bee9bf3613c5c45f514b2aca; expires=Sun, 01-Nov-2015 03:56:44 GMT; path=/; httponly
< Location: http://www.example.com/wp-admin/
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
Redirecting to http://www.example.com/wp-admin/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying <IP of example.com>...
* Connected to www.example.com (<IP of example.com>) port 80 (#1)
> GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Host: www.example.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip

< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Sat, 17 Oct 2015 15:56:45 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 285
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=30
* Server Apache/2 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
< Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Location: http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Age: 0
< 
* Connection #1 to host www.example.com left intact
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&amp;reauth=1">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

As you can see, libcurl is sending the GET without any cookies. Thus WordPress redirects me back to the login page asking for re-authorization. Also it seems bizarre that upon sending the GET request, it didn't say "* Found bundle for host example.com:..." like it did when I POSTed.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: It does not reproduce in my experiments. In order to get reliable output, you need to flush stdout before doing any output of your own. Otherwise you may get your output out of order. You may want to post your complete code.

Comment: I reformatted my question. @n.m. Are you trying to reproduce on a WordPress blog? Or another sort of page with a login?

Comment: No, I don't have WordPress, I use another page with a login, name;ly livejournal.com. You have not posted complete code. There's no `main` function, no `#include` directives. A person that wishes to reproduce your results needs to waste completely unnecesary efforts. Please provide **complete** code.

Comment: I have now created a site on wordpress.com. Your code works with it without a problem (after I change http to https and add SSL_library_init() and replace ParseLoginPageForPOSTParameters with hardcoded values `rememberme=forever&testcookie=1`. All cookies are sent out as they should be. So you may want to either divulge your real site for me to try, or alternatively build libcurl with debug info and dive in.

Comment: Added the complete code. @n.m. Do you think https makes a difference? When logging in manually, its not https. Ah, I see that the free wordpress blogs hosted on wordpress.com are https.

Comment: I don't know. Wordpress.com login doesn't work with http at all, it immediately redirects to https. You may want to try https, though if your site allows http logins I don't see how it would make a difference. I did the following: added `#include <openssl/ssl.h>`, added a call to `SSL_library_init()` as the first thing in `main`, added `-lssl`, and changed `http` to `https`. It logs in to wordpress.com.

Comment: This is bizarre. I created another wordpress and was going to give you a test login to give it a try, but when I run it with my code, it behaves correctly. It finds the bundle and reuses the connection. I cant figure out why that's not happening in my original case. Everything I do in the newly hosted blog has no problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is a bit weird, however valid I suppose.

My initial request to the webpage is to "http://example.com" addresses.

However the redirect is to a "http://www.example.com" address.

libcurl treats new address as completely new because of the "www."

I suppose this is technically valid behavior.